# Sync Redux State with Firebase Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

Please tell me if I am oversimplifying.

I have build a working React + Redux web app prototype, working theoretically as I would like using redux-persist and rehydrating from local storage each time.

I feel as though, given that this works perfectly, there should be some available middleware out there to sync my Redux store with Firebase (or some other tool).

All the tools out there seem to be exposing Firebase directly to me, whereas I feel that my Redux store should be able to act as an abstraction/caching layer over Firebase.

I have looked into all of the popular libraries (and many less popular), for example:

https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase

This guy seems to have the same idea:

https://medium.com/@david.gilbertson/react-and-firebase-sittin-in-a-tree-a00d481786cb

Any guidance or am I totally going down the wrong track? My expectation would be to never have to directly reference a Firebase Ref in my main code and to not change what I already have.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to take the tree and dump it into firebase whole cloth in any meaningful/useful way.  Sending the entire tree over the wire for every update doesn't seem very sustainable anyway.  If you have more details on your use case that would upend what I'm saying, please add it to your question.

Comment: I'm definitely not saying to send over the entire tree. But to me, it seems reasonable to have some async logic looking at the store and making updates to firebase and visa versa without the programmer having to worry and just programming redux synchronously.

Comment: @iamyojimbo were you able to find a solution? I am having same issue

Comment: I never found a solution other than manually building out an integration for my use case. Seems like a  cool library to build though.